# Use extracted value as parameter in SCREENSHOT command [iMacros]

Tags: imacros

I'm beginner in iMacros scripting and I'm trying to do the following:

1.Extract some data from page (call it "address")

2. Save screenshot of that page and save it with "address" name

I've got this code, which successfully extracts the data from page and saves the screenshot with static "lol.png" name, but I don't know how to save it with dynamical name (which is extracted from page). I found some solutions using VB but i need everything to be done within iMacros file.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:dijit_form_FilteringSelect_0 EXTRACT=TXT
SCREENSHOT TYPE=PAGE FOLDER=E:\lol FILE=lol.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:dijit_form_FilteringSelect_0 EXTRACT=TXT
SET extr {{!EXTRACT}}
SCREENSHOT TYPE=PAGE FOLDER=E:\fax FILE={{extr}}.png
```